# Rails Minitest custom model validation test doesn't create an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've got a `User` model with validation when new user has an account_type set as `'organisation'` the `company_name` should be mandatory.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ACCOUNT_TYPES = %w[individual organisation].freeze

  validates :company_name, presence: true, if: :organisation_account?

  private

  def organisation_account?
    account_type == ACCOUNT_TYPES[1]
  end
end
```

I want to test this validation using Minitest and Shoulda Matchers, like below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = users(:active)
  end

  context 'validations' do
    context 'when account_type is organisation' do
      @user.account_type = 'organisation'

      should validate_presence_of(:company_name)
    end
  end
```

But the test show me an error: `undefined method account_type=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` which means that for some reason the `setup` block does not create a user. What did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

> What did I missed?

Your tests should be in an `it` block. `context` blocks merely set up test environment, they don't define tests.

And, since there's not a single test in this file, the `setup` block didn't run.

Comment: You mean `test` block since it's a Minitest. I get rid of `context` replacing it by `test do` block and now it looks like shoulda matcher is not working because I've got an error: `UserTest#test_validations:
NoMethodError: undefined method should' for #<UserTest:0x00007fd6cedb8d58>`.

Comment: @mr_muscle: I myself am an rspec guy indeed, but some minitest examples I've seen on the internet do use `it` for defining tests. This one, for example: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest-context. As for shoulda-matcher, I don't use that too. I either don't test built-in validations if they're simple, or I feed bad input and assert resulting error messages.

Comment: That's what I thought but anyway, unfortunately your answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: @mr_muscle: it does answer the question, though ("why is `@user` nil?"). shoulda-matcher issue is a separate problem, out of scope here.